# Dynamics Connection SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like some explanations on how to create and set up a dynamic connection to SQL Server DB engine in a C # project

Comment: dynamic connectionn ??? or creating connection string dynamically and than try to connect

Comment: You mean put a connection string in the `config` file and then call it in your code? Your question is not very clear can you clarify what is it exactly you're after

Comment: @PranayRana  Can be possible creating dynamic connection? Eventually creating connection string dynamically

Comment: @Izzy yes, you got what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

if you want connection string in config and read it than you need to do like this , put possible connectionstring in config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CharityManagement" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CharityManagement;Integrated Security=True"/>
<add name="CharityManagement_two" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CharityManagement_two;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and than read it base on condition using configurationmanager class

```
//to read first connection string
var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement"].ConnectionString;

   //to read second connection string
    var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement_two"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I've tried and I got this error:Exception first-chance di tipo 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll

Comment: @CristianMagrini -  check on google and configure connection string property ...error is rlated to things are not configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're after

In the `config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then to read the connection string in your code you will do

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Don't forget to use `using System.Configuration;`

Further reading **[here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)**

Comment: Yes, But I need that the connection is valid for all machine that run the application

Comment: What application is it? winform, web forms.. etc?

Comment: The application is winform

Comment: I'm sorry but you've confused me a little with *But I need that the connection is valid for all machine that run the application*

Comment: I want predispose a connectionString that is validating for each pc that executing program